# get undefined is not an object when trying to stripe.init

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

I am trying to use tipsi-stripe and when calling stripe.init I am getting the following error

Code

```
import stripe from 'tipsi-stripe'

stripe.init({
  publishableKey: 'key',
  // merchantId: 'merchant_id', // Optional
})
```

Error

[image]

Comment: make sure you are using the correct version of strip library with the  correct react native version u are using

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error before when I forgot to link native modules. It seems like you have not linked a native module.

Make sure you do

```
react-native link tipsi-stripe
```

or

```
rnpm link
```